# Get values from list of list/tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to obtain the first value of each list of list based on the 3rd value in the list - if it's `-3`, then take first value of that list.

The initial list of list looks like:

```
 [['GRRSCLOE1', <DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' LMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>, -3.0, 'RR'], ['GRTFRAIX1', <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>, 1.0, 'P'], ['GRAMDZGP1', <DstTzInfo 'America/Argentina/Mendoza' LMT-1 day, 19:25:00 STD>, -3.0, 'P+PE'], ['GRASAOTB2', <DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' LMT-1 day, 20:54:00 STD>, -3.0, 'PE'], ['GRTVAPEM4', <DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' LMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>, -3.0, 'P']
```

This is the desired result :

```
['GRRSCLOE1','GRAMDZGP1','GRASAOTB2','GRTVAPEM4']
```

Comment: `[i[0] for i in your_list]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
l = [['GRRSCLOE1', <DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' LMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>, -3.0, 'RR'], ['GRTFRAIX1', <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>, 1.0, 'P'], ['GRAMDZGP1', <DstTzInfo 'America/Argentina/Mendoza' LMT-1 day, 19:25:00 STD>, -3.0, 'P+PE'], ['GRASAOTB2', <DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' LMT-1 day, 20:54:00 STD>, -3.0, 'PE'], ['GRTVAPEM4', <DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' LMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>, -3.0, 'P']]
new_list = [i[0] for i in l if int(i[2])==-3]
```

Comment: Thanks great thanks, just what I needed. I was building an interconnected dropdown with ipywidgets.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**:

```
l = [['GRRSCLOE1', "<DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' LMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>", -3.0, 'RR'], ['GRTFRAIX1', "<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>", 1.0, 'P'], ['GRAMDZGP1', "<DstTzInfo 'America/Argentina/Mendoza' LMT-1 day, 19:25:00 STD>", -3.0, 'P+PE'], ['GRASAOTB2', "<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' LMT-1 day, 20:54:00 STD>", -3.0, 'PE'], ['GRTVAPEM4',"<DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' LMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>", -3.0, 'P']]
print([a[0] for a in l if float(a[2])==-3.0])
```

**output**:

```
['GRRSCLOE1', 'GRAMDZGP1', 'GRASAOTB2', 'GRTVAPEM4']
```

**Explanations:**

First of all your initial list strings should be surrounded by double or simple quotes, if you have single quotes in the string and you do not want to escape them, use double quotes.

Then what you are looking for is list comprehensions:

- The construction `[ <operation on a> for a in list if <condition on a>]` will allow you to return a list containing all the elements x of your initial list that fulfill the condition
- This would return all the nested lists of your example, as you are interested only by the first element replace `<operation on a>` by `a[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
[i[0] for i in given_list if i[2] == -3]
```

This might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `itemgetter()` to get elements from sublists:

```
from operator import itemgetter

iget = itemgetter(0, 2)

gen = (iget(subl) for subl in lst)
[i for i, j in gen if j == -3]
```